# pip failing to install specific packages: error 1 (kivy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, pip, kivy

I am able to install most packages, but some specific packages are failing. One I am consistently failing is Kivy. I have tried updating, as well as full reinstall of pip, setuptools, distutils, etc. I also have followed all recommendations on the kivy site and can not quite figure out the issue. Here is my error printout from cmd prompt:

```
C:\Users\user1>py -m pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz (23.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-7w75s0h9\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0an0tu7h\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (10 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-60.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (958 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.21,>=0.24
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1
    Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1 (from versions: 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/96/091ddacafb84dd18555a32d860dbfaf9c806147aa30c6f3c8b93cb7bab97/Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=d25e44eb44e43762b2fd0c5874e51954e0f1181fd9800d8a6756be6d084812d8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/kivy/). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-7w75s0h9\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0an0tu7h\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... -
```

It then loops through all previous kivy versions, and fails them as well.

Comment: It looks like you are using python 3.10. Kivy as of not is does not support 3.10. Try 3.9 instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy 2.0 only supports Python 2.7 to 3.9 at the moment, so make sure your Python version is compatible. If you are using the latest version of Python, than you wont be able to install kivy.